# Algebraic geometry and topology for string theory

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, compactification, algebraic-geometry, calabi-yau

I am looking for a comprehensive book or notes in **algebraic geometry and topology techniques used in string theory compactifications** covering topics like orientifolds, orbiolds, Calabi Yau manifolds and toric geometry, divisors, resolution of singularities, fiber bundles etc.

If it contains explicit examples and exercises it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Lecture notes by Candelas:- lectures on Complex manifolds  [https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=Y29sb3JhZG8uZWR1fHRhc2ktMjAxNy13aWtpfGd4OjEyMzQ4M2MyZDNmOWMyNmM]

This notes mainly deals with complex manifolds like Calabi Yau, Kahler Manifolds, Chern classes etc.

2. "String theory and M theory" by Becker, Becker, and Schwarz
   This book has a separate chapter on Compactification and String geometry. It contains some solved examples and exercises.